# To retrieve price for CVE-WT by GOOGLEFINANCE

Tags: google-finance

The price of CVE on TSX can be retrived by `=GOOGLEFINANCE("TSE:CVE", "price")` in Google Sheets. How does one get the price of CVE-WT using GOOGLEFINANCE?

Answer (score 1):

I can't find it on googlefinance. You can retrieve by yahoo :

```
function marketPrice(code) {
  var url='https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/'+code
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  var jsonString = source.match(/(?<=root.App.main = ).*(?=}}}})/g) + '}}}}'
  var data = JSON.parse(jsonString)
  var regularMarketPrice = data.context.dispatcher.stores.StreamDataStore.quoteData[code].regularMarketPrice.raw
  return regularMarketPrice
}
function test() {Logger.log(marketPrice('CVE-WT'))}
```

Comment: This works. Thanks. I am using this as a workaround. Still hope GOOGLEFINANCE works...